# Python - download de imagem via url

Tags: python, url, request, download, image

Alguma forma de baixar imagens com o python?

Eu sei que existe uma maneira com o bs4, porém não sei qual é, mas aceito qualquer possibilidade

url como exemplo:
http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRBL_Z4t3zlPVfo4WLFmVy9CE2zBLph8hmwoexfOQn1kQOHoTDAu9dLCsI4

Comment: Precisa ser com bs4? O que exatamente você quer fazer? Apenas fazer o download de uma imagem que você tem o link ou efetuar o parser do HTML e baixar todas as imagens?

Comment: não, não precisa ser pelo bs4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem várias formas de fazer isso, veja dois exemplos, utilizando bibliotecas distintas.

---

Utilizando a `requests`:

```
import requests

with open('pato.jpg', 'wb') as imagem:
  resposta = requests.get("http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRBL_Z4t3zlPVfo4WLFmVy9CE2zBLph8hmwoexfOQn1kQOHoTDAu9dLCsI4", stream=True)

  if not resposta.ok:
    print("Ocorreu um erro, status:" , resposta.status_code)
  else:
    for dado in resposta.iter_content(1024):
      if not dado:
          break

      imagem.write(dado)

    print("Imagem salva! =)")
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/PeriodicDarkgreyLaboratory

---

Utilizando a `urllib`:

```
import urllib.request
import sys

try:
  urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRBL_Z4t3zlPVfo4WLFmVy9CE2zBLph8hmwoexfOQn1kQOHoTDAu9dLCsI4", "pato.jpg")
  print("Imagem salva! =)")
except:
  erro = sys.exc_info()
  print("Ocorreu um erro:", erro)
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/FrigidLovelyLoaderprogram

Comment: muito obrigado!